# how to fetch String array in android

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I need help to fetch JSON from RESTfull API.

> This is my Response

```
"variation_details": [
    {
        "variation_title": "Black Color",
        "specifications": "Diamond Cut",
        "image": [
            "/uploads/variation-img0-0-Redmi J812127868.jpg"
        ],
        "quantity": 10,
        "price": 20000
    }
],
```

> how can i remove [] this. from response because i need to display image in view Pager
>
> This is how i get From response
> http://devapi.dicatto.com[/uploads/variation-img0-0-Redmi J812127868.jpg]
>
> this is my full response

```
{
    "code": true,
    "success": "Records fetched successfully",
    "result": {
        "name": "Redmi J812127868",
        "main_category": "5cde6e836340c5659e5c6992",
        "sub_category": "5cde6f199aed456592c98f98",
        "brand": "5cdeab466340c5659e5c69bd",
        "model": "PROD771100",
        "currency": "Rs",
        "mrp_price": 18000,
        "retailer_price": 17000,
        "quantity": 30,
        "available_quantity": null,
        "avg_ratings": null,
        "description": null,
        "performance": null,
        "other_infomation": null,
        "product_description": "Test1234",
        "specifications": "<p>RAM-4&nbsp;</p>\n",
        "features": [
            {
                "title": "RAM:4 GB,Memory:64 GB",
                "description": "Test",
                "image": "/uploads/feature-img0-Redmi J812127868.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "warranty": "12 Months",
        "replacement": "Screen",
        "same_day_delivery": null,
        "discounted_amount": 2000,
        "cash_on_delivery": null,
        "manufacturing_details": "Test1232",
        "importer_details": "Mumbai Test1232",
        "packers_details": "Test123",
        "offers": null,
        "highlights": "Mumbai",
        "more_info": null,
        "keywords": null,
        "manufacturer": null,
        "variation_theme": "color",
        "variation_details": [
            {
                "variation_title": "Black Color",
                "specifications": "Diamond Cut",
                "image": [
                    "/uploads/variation-img0-0-Redmi J812127868.jpg"
                ],
                "quantity": 10,
                "price": 20000
            }
        ],
        
        
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

> The response change when multiple image come

```
"variation_details": [
    {
        "variation_title": "Black Color",
        "specifications": "Diamond Cut",
        "image": [
            "/uploads/variation-img0-0-Redmi J812127868.jpg",
            "/uploads/variation-img0-1-Redmi J812127868.jpg"
        ],
        "quantity": 10,
        "price": 20000
    }
],
```

Comment: `[]` represent list of items. So if you dont need list then just define one instance of details/image.

Comment: bro it come list in array in this key image can you show some snippet to remove this  []

Comment: you don't want image key in you json correct?

Comment: tranform your input to output by changing array/list by taking just '0'th index item (assuming you would always get one item of image/variation details.)

Comment: @Vishalkumarsinghvi no i need image Key to fetch from API

Comment: @SMA i have assume 0 index in the list but [] this is not remove

Comment: share your model and i will let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variation_details.java

```
public class Variation_details
{
    private String[] image;

    private String quantity;

    private String price;

    private String specifications;

    private String variation_title;

    public String[] getImage ()
    {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage (String[] image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getQuantity ()
    {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity (String quantity)
    {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getPrice ()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice (String price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getSpecifications ()
    {
        return specifications;
    }

    public void setSpecifications (String specifications)
    {
        this.specifications = specifications;
    }

    public String getVariation_title ()
    {
        return variation_title;
    }

    public void setVariation_title (String variation_title)
    {
        this.variation_title = variation_title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [image = "+image+", quantity = "+quantity+", price = "+price+", specifications = "+specifications+", variation_title = "+variation_title+"]";
    }
}
```

Variation_details.getImage()[0]; you can fetch image key

Comment: check syntax may be some problem logic you can find above.

Comment: Thanks bro i get response finally but in that image key if it comes list["",""] like this its show in list..??

Comment: you mean to say that multiple images

Comment: you want to display all image in somewhere

Comment: yes in viewPager like flip kart  to show phone images multiple

Comment: for(String i:variantion_details.getImage()){  
    //take i and append in viewpager or store somewhere 
   } ref:-https://www.javatpoint.com/for-each-loop

Comment: for(String i:oneProductModel.getProductObject().getSub_images())
                        { //take i and append in viewpager or store somewhere
                            Log.d("Product_data", "onResponse: "+"http://devapi.dicatto.com"+oneProductModel.getProductObject()
                                    .getVariationDetails().get(0).getImage()[Integer.parseInt(i)]);

                             }

Comment: bro i have update my question how response come when multi image come

Comment: "Response should be "base url"+fetch image uri use your model =http://devapi.dicatto.com/uploads/variation-img0-0-Redmi J812127868.jpg

Comment: use for loop and store in arraylist and display now i am done for this problem keep trying .

Comment: you can also use ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 0):

Use Pojo to Get Response data easily.

With Pojo You can get All YOur response data correctly and with easy method.